# UIButton's title mysteriously disappears when sliding back too fast

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uibutton, ios8

I have a UIButton in the main screen, of which title should always show the currently playing or to-be-played music, if the playlist is empty, it should show "Music", clicking it will bring up a song selecting screen(when playlist empty) or a play list screen(when playlist not empty), after selecting a song and go to playlist screen, and delete the song and slide back to the main screen, the title of UIButton should show "Music".

Here's the problem: when you are sliding back too fast, the "Music" text would show up in a split second and then disappears, but when you are sliding slowly, the "Music" text stays.

I've recorded the very strange behavior in [**this 25-second video**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=STtkHyh8ZfA).

Here's the related code:

```
- (void)updateChooseMusicButton {
    if(self.songQueue.count == 0) {
        [self.chooseMusicButton setTitle:@"Music" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    } 
}

- (void)setChooseMusicButton:(UIButton *)chooseMusicButton {
    _chooseMusicButton = chooseMusicButton;
    [_chooseMusicButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [_chooseMusicButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution: Change the type of the button to "Custom", it was using "System". And it also takes care of the flashing when title changes.

Answer (score 0):

Comment this code and try to run..

```
- (void)setChooseMusicButton:(UIButton *)chooseMusicButton {
        _chooseMusicButton = chooseMusicButton;
        [_chooseMusicButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [_chooseMusicButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
}
```

and call the updateChooseMusicButton function in viewWillAppear method.

Comment: in updateChooseMusicButton function add this line.. [self.chooseMusicButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateSelected];

Comment: I tried setcolor for all UIControlStates for that button, didn't work.